# How to show subtraction value using php loop?

Tags: php

For example :

`$monthly_bill = 700`
`$paid_amount = 2100`

Now I want to use a php loop which will print me `700`, `700` and `400` to each line. How can I do this ?

**I am doing following code but not working :**

```
<?php
$paid_amount = 1800;
$monthly_bill = 700;
$counting_month = round($paid_amount / $monthly_bill);
for ($x=1; $x<=$counting_month; $x++) {         
    echo $insert = $paid_amount - $monthly_bill;
    $paid_amount = $insert;
    echo '<br/>';   
}
```

Comment: And "not working" means _what_ exactly?

Comment: You should look with division operator `/`, modulo operator `%`, and floor() function. `floor(1800/700) = 2`, `1800%700 = 400`, so you know that you have 2 full month and one not full with 400 only

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `for` loop. Those run a fixed number of times, and your loop would keep running until well after the money runs out.

Use a `do` instead, and have its termination clause be when the money runs out:

```
$remaining = 1800;
$monthly = 700;
do {
   echo $monthly;
   $remaining -= $monthly;
   if ($remaining < $monthly) {
      $monthly = $remaining;
   }
} while ($remaining > 0);
```

Comment: Working for me but should be closing tag after if statement.

Comment: can I count within this `do` loop. I need to show 1 2 3...etc.

Comment: yes, you could have a counter. and thinking about it, you could just use your `for` loop, you just need to `break;` out of it when the money runs out. the math remains the same.

Comment: Why provide code without letting him to find the solution himself ..?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$amount = 1800;
$monthlybill = 700;

for ($i=0; $i<$amount/$monthlybill; $i++) {
    echo "paid for " . ($i+1) . " month =" . $monthlybill . "<br>\n";
    $amount -= $monthlybill;
}
if ($amount>0) {
    echo "paid for " . ($i+1) . " month =" . $amount;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but could you please indent your code according to normal standards so that it gets readable? Thanks.

Comment: No, "according to normal standards". I did not ask to _remove_ all indentation.

Comment: I fixed things for you.

Comment: Why don't you use modulo and division instead of doing all this code ?

Comment: @Julqas according to question easily implemented code provided he can optimize it